# Understanding generator functions in Python

Tags: python, generator

Why it outputs `None`?

```
def hello():
    print("hello")

def gen():
    yield hello();
    yield hello();
    yield hello();

for x in gen():
    print(x)
```

result is:

```
hello 
None 
hello 
None 
hello 
None
```

why None is printed?? 
not hello * 3 ?

Comment: `hello()` does not return => implicitly returns `None`.  `hello() is None`

Comment: Maybe you meant this: `def hello(): return "hello"` ?

Comment: I recommend reading functions first.

Comment: [Defining functions - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: The purpose of generators is to generate values - here, the `None` values returned by `hello()`. Printing 'hello' during that process is just a side effect of your `hello()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it prints None**:

Here when you `print()` but doesnt `return` anything, python will add a `return` automatically at the end.

Let's see an example using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)

```
import dis

def hello():
  print('hello')

dis.dis(hello)
```

output:

```
      0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
      3 PRINT_ITEM          
      4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
      5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
      8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Let's see now when you return an explicit values:

```
import dis

def hello():
  return 'hello'

dis.dis(hello)
```

output:

```
    0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
    3 RETURN_VALUE
```

See, the `LOAD_CONST 0 (None)` was not called the second times. Therefore, the first value being loaded was return.

**What you should do to improve your code**:

Do this, if you just need to print "hello" inside the `hello` function.

```
def hello():
    print("hello")

def gen():
    yield hello()
    yield hello()
    yield hello()

for x in gen():
    x
```

OR, use return value, in that case you need to return instead of printing.

```
def hello():
    return "hello"
    ^ Here I return rather than print hello

def gen():
    yield hello()
    yield hello()
    yield hello()

for x in gen():
    print(x)
```

But it is weird to call several `yield`, better do a loop to avoid a `StopIteration`

e.g

```
def hello():
    return "hello"

def gen():
    while True:
        yield hello()

x = gen()

for i in range(3):
  print(x.next())
```

Answer (score 0):

By **default** functions return `None` type.

```
def hello():
    pass

def gen():
    yield hello();
    yield hello();
    yield hello();

for x in gen():
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
```

## What are generators?

The main difference between generators and functions is that you can obtain values on the fly. And after one value is `yield`'ed by the generator. and next value is returned the old one is not **stored in the memory**.

## Iterating over a generator

```
def hello():
    for x in range(3):
        yield x*x


for i in hello():
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
```

Now using `next()`

```
def hello():
    for x in range(3):
        yield x*x

gen = hello()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(gen))
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
```

So far so good. Right? `gen = hello()` here `gen` becomes a generator object.

## Iterating over a list

```
my_list = [x*x for x in range(3)]
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
```

**Same output?** Yes same output. But only difference here is that I can use the `my_list` iterable any number of times I want,

```
my_list = [x*x for x in range(3)]
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
print("\n")
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
4

0
1
4
```

However if I try to use the **Generator** when it is exhausted.

```
def hello():
    for x in range(3):
        yield x*x

gen = hello()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(gen))
next(gen)
```

Output

```
0
1
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mr/sadas.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(next(gen))
StopIteration
```

How to overcome this? Create a new generator object again and use.

```
def hello():
    for x in range(3):
        yield x*x

gen = hello()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(gen))

gen = hello()

for i in range(3):
    print(next(gen))
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
0
1
4
```

You see the difference? Hope I was clear.